# Numbers Too Big While Trying To Solve Leetcode Unique Paths Problem

Tags: java

I am trying to solve the [Unique Paths](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths/) problem from LeetCode. Basically, the problem is you're given an `m` by `n` grid, and you have to count the number of paths from the top left to the bottom right while only going down or right.

I am doing the mathematical approach, which is pretty complicated to figure out but the basic formula is this:

`(m - 1 + n - 1) choose (min(m - 1, n - 1))`, and the formula for `n choose r` is `n! / (r! * (n-r)!)`.

This approach works well, but eventually the factorial goes past the integer limit, so it becomes negative. The next thing I tried was to change everything to long, but then again the numbers became too big for long, too. How can I simplify the numbers so it stays under the limit? Here is my code:

```
public int uniquePaths(int m, int n) { // The method being called
    return (int) (m == 1 || n == 1 ? 1 : choose((m - 1) + (n - 1), Math.min(m - 1, n - 1)));
}

private long choose(long n, long r) { // Calculated n choose r
    return fact(n) / (fact(r) * fact(n - r));
}

private long fact(long n) { // Calculates factorial of n
    return n == 1 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

I know it's possible to simplify it because the answer is an integer, so the number should easily fall under `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: HINT: you don't need actually need to compute and divide the factorials of `a` and `b` in order to compute `a! / b!`, `a! / b! = a * (a-1) * (a-2) * ... * (a - b + 1)`.  And don't forget that `a/bc = a/b * b/c`, so `n! / (r! (n-r)!)` now becomes `(n!/r!) * (n!/(n-r)!)`.

Comment: The max value of m or n can be 100. The factorial of 100 (100!) is 158 digits long. You are even calculating the fact of larger number. No int, long data type would be able to hold this type of huge number. You can use BigInteger class of java as you are using java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. What I need to do is cancel out the bigger number in the denominator. If `r` is bigger than `n-r`, then the formula becomes this:

`n * n-1 * n-2 ... * r+1 / (n-r)!`

And if `n-r` is bigger than `r`, the formula becomes this:

`n * n-1 * n-2 ... * (n-r)+1 / r!`

This makes the bigger number in the denominator smaller and `n!` smaller too. Here is my code in the end:

```
public int uniquePaths(int m, int n) { // Method being called
    return (int) (m == 1 || n == 1 ? 1 : choose((m - 1) + (n - 1), Math.min(m - 1, n - 1)));
}

private long choose(long n, long r) { // Calculates n choose r
    return r > n - r ? fact(n, r) / fact(n - r) : fact(n, n - r) / fact(r);
}

private long fact(long n) { // Calculates n!
    return n == 1 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1);
}

private long fact(long n, long lower) { // Calculates n! with lower bound of lower; that is n * n-1 * n-2 ... * lower+1.
    return n == lower ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1, lower);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here after updating your code to use BigInteger class of java, it got accepted.

```
import java.math.BigInteger; 

class Solution {
    public int uniquePaths(int m, int n) { // The method being called
        BigInteger mB = BigInteger.valueOf(m);
        BigInteger nB = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
        BigInteger ans =  
                (mB.equals(BigInteger.ONE) || nB.equals(BigInteger.ONE) ? 
                BigInteger.ONE :
                choose(mB.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).add(nB.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)), 
                  mB.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).min(nB.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))));

        return ans.intValue();
    }

    private BigInteger choose(BigInteger n, BigInteger r) { // Calculated n choose r
        return fact(n).divide((fact(r).multiply(fact(n.subtract(r)))));
    }

    private BigInteger fact(BigInteger n) { // Calculates factorial of n
        return n.equals(BigInteger.ONE) ? 
            BigInteger.ONE : 
            n.multiply(fact(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I never heard of `BigInteger` before, I should probably use it more. However, the problem I'm finding is that it's too slow. On my LeetCode submission, I only got 11% in run-time. Is there any way I can speed it up, or is it just an affect of `BigInteger`?